# Copy specific cells from an excel document using C++

Tags: c++, windows, excel, ms-office, copy-paste

I have been looking into trying to manipulate an excel document using C++. Basically what I want to do is access an excel document and copy a specified line from that document to the windows clipboard. 
I haven't found any libraries I am able to use or any commands I can use to accomplish this task. If anyone can point me to any documentation or examples that show me how to get this accomplished it would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's a lot of work, bro - too much that can be reasonably covered in a SO answer. Your question is unfortunately, too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so using Excel's COM object.  Microsoft provides examples in all their languages, here's one in C++

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216686

And another, more recent one also from Microsoft

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2012/03/17/sample-of-mar-17th-excel-automation-in-c-c-and-vb.aspx

It's not an easy subject, the interfaces offered are quite extensive, but it's quite popular and thus lots of examples and reading material can be found.

EDIT: do you have to do this in C++?  Because you can do exactly the same thing using the same COM object but using Powershell.  Have a look here

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/09/08/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-automate-microsoft-excel.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this reference, I'm a bit new at C++ so it is a little confusing but it's a start and will certainly help.

Comment: The only reason I am leaning toward C++ is because that is the language I am more familiar with. I know a little java, but I am more fluent with C++. I will look into using powershell, but it is going to take quite a bit to learn a whole separate language. Any suggestions on where to start learning Powershell?

Comment: As Powershell is Microsoft's new scripting language it's preinstalled on all newish Windows machines, and there are tons of resources both from MS and third parties that discuss Powershell.  I have no specific recommendation for a resource, I got started with what MS offers and some blogs on the subject.